# Loading XML data from SQL Server into Teradata

Tags: sql-server, xml, teradata

I am trying to load XML column (along with multiple other columns) from MS SQL to Teradata. The column datatype is XML in both the server. I am using TPT to extract and load. I am using TPT ODBC Operator to extract the data from the SQL Server and TPT Inserter Operator to insert the data into Teradata table. But during the insert, I am getting "Parsing error" even though the XML data is in correct format. I verified it using different validators.

I went through the Teradata Documentation (https://docs.teradata.com/r/NMjDGHKjr0Tkeos1ItQDhA/GXKdU6AYKUeNIieLN7JJKA) and I found the following statement regarding the ODBC Operator.

> The ODBC operator does not support extracting LOB data from the third-party server and loading it to Teradata table. The operator can extract the LOB data, but does not prepare the data in Teradata format, which has 8-byte length preceding the data.

Now, my question is there any way to overcome this issue or there any other alternatives to load the XML from SQL Server to Teradata. I am not able to attach any code or data as they are confidential.

Comment: Your code + data might be confidential, but that doesn't stop you building a test [mre] with test data and test code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: If your XML data is short enough, you might be able to override the TPT schema to VARCHAR. Otherwise you may need to find another tool.